# Limitação no número de itens retornado do Facebook

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, feed

Tenho uma aplicação que recupera o feed de notícias de um grupo que eu posto.

O problema é que, eu só consigo recuperar os últimos 25 itens cadastrados, Tem alguma forma de recuperar mais do que isso?

**Edit:**

Meu código atual para recuperar os itens é:

```
$response = $fb->get(
    $groupId . '/feed?fields=full_picture, message, picture, link, is_published, from'
    , $accessToken
);
```

Basicamente faço uma requisição **GET** na **API** do Facebook informando os campos que eu preciso que seja retornado via **json**. 
As variaveis `$groupId e $accessToken`, possuem os valores do Id do grupo cujo qual estou tentando recuparar as informações, e a outra como o próprio nome diz é o access token necessário para realizar a consulta na **API**.

Comment: Por favor, adicione mais detalhes à sua pergunta e, se possível, o seu código atual. Dessa forma a comunidade poderá ajudá-lo mais rapidamente.

Comment: Olá Paulo, eu atualizei a pergunta com um pouco mais de informações e o código que eu utilizo, espero estar mais claro agora :)

Comment: Reveja a API do Facebook, vê se esse não é o limite da própria Facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, tente isso em seu código:

```
$response = $fb->get(
    $groupId . '/feed?fields&limit=10=full_picture, message, picture, link, is_published, from'
    , $accessToken
);
```

limit=**10** - Números de itens que o Facebook vai retornar.

Comment: Olá Matheus, acabei encontrando essa solução tbm....mas sem esse "limit", vc sabe se teria como retornar um número grande de itens?

Comment: @GuiPab você trocou o 10 pelo o tanto de itens que você quer?

Comment: Sim sim fiz isso e me atendeu a momento.....porém e quando eu quiser recuperar TODOS os itens manja?

Comment: @GuiPab eu acho que o limite é  200-225 posts.